# Rails 3 - Invoke controller method with submit_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm very new to rails, so please excuse me if I'm asking such a basic question.

I had this form on my html.erb page:

```
<%= form_tag(posts_path(:controller => "posts", :action => "create_thread"), :method => "post") do%>
   Title: 
   <br></br>
   <%= text_area_tag 'title', 'Thread\'s title is required!', :rows => 1, :cols => 30 %>
   <br></br>
   Message: 
   <br></br>
   <%= text_area_tag 'body', nil, :rows => 15, :cols => 50 %>
   <br></br>
   <%= submit_tag "Create Thread" %>
<% end %>
```

I defined the "create_thread" method in the controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def create_thread
      logger.info("Thread created: ")
    end
end
```

In the routes.rb file, I created a route for the submit:

```
resources :posts do
collection do
  post 'index', :as => :create_thread
end
```

Basically, when I click on the "Create Thread" button on the form, I would like rails to execute the function "create_thread" in the PostsController class, and then load the "index" page.

However, when I clicked on the "Create Thread" button, it took me straight to the "index" page (so the path is working, at least), but it did not execute the "create_thread" function in the controller.

This was what it showed on the console when I clicked on the button:

```
Started POST "/posts?action=create_thread" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-14 22:08:35 -0700
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9XVUrStaysmdOc6ug/A3XXX/8bzLkY8ixCkiAfHs9fU=", "title"=>"Thread's title is required!", "body"=>"", "commit"=>"Create Thread"}
```

Here's the output of rake routes

```
               root        /                                   posts#index
   new_thread_posts GET    /posts/new_thread(.:format)         posts#new_thread
create_thread_posts POST   /posts(.:format)                    posts#index
current_thread_post GET    /posts/:id/current_thread(.:format) posts#current_thread
              posts GET    /posts(.:format)                    posts#index
                    POST   /posts(.:format)                    posts#create
           new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                posts#new
          edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)           posts#edit
               post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                posts#show
                    PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                posts#update
                    DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                posts#destroy
```

So, how do I get rails to execute the "create_thread" function in PostsController? I have been searching over the web in the past 2 days, and trying all sorts of stuff, but none has worked for me.

Any hint or pointer would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: add the output of 'rake routes'

Comment: did you try to use redirect_to inside your create_thread action after logging?

Comment: @prasad.surase I have updated the post with the output of rake routes. Thanks

Comment: @SaidKaldybaev I'm sorry to be ignorant. Would you please elaborate what you meant? Rails didn't even seem to touch the create_thread method, so how would putting redirect_to inside create_thread would help in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
resources :posts do
  post :create_thread, on: :collection
end

form_tag(controller: :posts, action: :create_thread)
```

Comment: Thank you.That almost works! It gave me the error "can't use collection outside resource(s) scope" in the routes.rb. The error is from "post :create_thread, on: :collection". If I commented out the ", on:collection" part, then it executed the create_thread method. But now, it says "Missing template posts/create_thread". I don't want to create another "create_thread.html.erb" page. I would like it to just go back to the index page, so in routes, I tried "post :create_thread, 'index'", but that didn't seem to work (the function was executed, but got error "missing template posts/create_thread".

Comment: Bingo! If I put "redirect_to posts_path" inside the create_thread method (in addition to modifying the routes.rb and form_tag() like you suggested), then it worked! The create_thread method was executed, and rails took me back to the index page afterward. However, I'm just wondering is there away to do it in routes.rb instead of inside the create_thread method.

Comment: You should be able to use `collection` in your route. Please read here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions